Determine the convergence of the series $\sum \frac{1}{(\ln{n})^{\ln{\ln{n}}}}$
$\sum \frac{1}{(\ln{n})^{\ln{\ln{n}}}}$
Can integral test help here? Other tests i know doesn`t work.

What have you tried? Does https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test help?

Hint: compare $(\ln n)^{\ln\ln n}=e^{(\ln\ln n)^2}$ to $n=e^{\ln n}$, then compare $x^2$ to $e^x$ for $x=\ln\ln n$.

@温泽海 yes it works, thank you. I just forgot about this test.

The series is divergent.
Let $k$ be a positive integer. For all positive integers $n$ with
\begin{equation*}
e^{e^{k}} \le n < e^{e^{k+1}}
\end{equation*}
we have
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
e^{k} & \le \log n < e^{k+1} \\
k & \le \log \log n < k + 1
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
(\log n)^{\log \log n} < e^{(k + 1)^{2}}
\end{equation*}
Therefore
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(\log n)^{\log \log n}} & \geq \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \sum_{n = \lceil e^{e^{k}} \rceil}^{\lceil e^{e^{k + 1}} \rceil - 1} \frac{1}{(\log n)^{\log \log n}} \geq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \bigg( \lceil e^{e^{k + 1}} \rceil - \lceil e^{e^{k}} \rceil \bigg) e^{- (k + 1)^{2}} \\
& \geq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \bigg(e^{e^{k + 1}} - e^{e^{k}} - 1 \bigg) e^{- (k + 1)^{2}} \geq \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} e^{e^{k}} e^{-(k + 1)^{2}} = \infty
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
Here we used the fact that for large $k$,
\begin{equation*}
e^{k} > (k + 1)^{2} \Rightarrow e^{e^{k}} e^{- (k + 1)^{2}} \geq 1
\end{equation*}
and the fact that for all integers $k \geq 1$,
\begin{equation*}
\big( e^{e^{k}} - 1 \big)^{2} \geq 2 \Rightarrow e^{2 e^{k}} - 2 e^{e^{k}} + 1 \geq 2 \Rightarrow e^{2 e^{k}} - e^{e^{k}} - 1 \geq e^{e^{k}} \Rightarrow e^{e^{k + 1}} - e^{e^{k}} - 1 \geq e^{e^{k}} 
\end{equation*}
